# How to add and write to a file in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am new to programming and would like some advice on how to proceed with this question.

I have a file with 10 math questions, but can't seem to figure out how to replace the underscores with the answer of each question.

```
1. 1 + 3 = __
2. 2 + 2 = __
3. 0 + 9 = __
4. 3 + 4 = __
5. 5 + 2 = __
6. 2 + 5 = __
7. 6 + 4 = __
8. 7 + 1 = __
9. 9 + 9 = __
10. 10 + -1 = __
```

I am able to open the text file and reading from it but can't seem to figure the way to add them and delete the underscores with the correct answer.

This is the code to read from the file.

```
File.open("math1.txt", 'r+') do |file|
  file.each_line do |line|
    puts line
  end
end
```

Comment: Show your code for reading the text file.

Comment: The easiest: read the file into data structures, change the data, write the data structures into file. Changing file is only possible if you are replacing an equal number of characters, and is much more touchy than just recreating the file.

Comment: Thanks, Stefan do you mind trying to explain how to make the code work, like extracting the operands and operators from the line and completing the code, I am new to this and it seems to be really hard for me.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

#### Extracting operands and operator from a string

You have to somehow extract the operands and operators from the line. I'd use a [regular expression](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Regexp.html):

```
re = /([-]?\d+) ([-+*\/]) ([-]?\d+)/
```

- `([-]?\d+)` is the 1st capturing group

  - `[-]?` match the literal character `-` zero or one time
  - `\d+` match a digit (0-9) one ore more times
- `([-+*\/])` is the 2nd capturing group

  - `[-+*\/]` match the characters `-`, `+`, `*` or `/` (must be escaped) once
- `([-]?\d+)` is the 3rd, capturing group, same as the 1st

Examples using [`match`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Regexp.html#method-i-match):

```
re.match("1. 1 + 3 = __")  #=> #<MatchData "1 + 3" 1:"1" 2:"+" 3:"3">
re.match("7. 6 + 4 = __")  #=> #<MatchData "6 + 4" 1:"6" 2:"+" 3:"4">
re.match("10. 10 + -1")    #=> #<MatchData "10 + -1" 1:"10" 2:"+" 3:"-1">
```

The capturing groups are can be retrieved from the [`MatchData`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/MatchData.html):

```
m = re.match("7. 6 + 4 = __")  #=> #<MatchData "6 + 4" 1:"6" 2:"+" 3:"4">
m[1] #=> "6"
m[2] #=> "+"
m[3] #=> "4"
```

And they are also stored (from left to right) in [special global variables](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Special+global+variables) `$1`, `$2` and `$3`:

```
re.match("7. 6 + 4 = __")  #=> #<MatchData "6 + 4" 1:"6" 2:"+" 3:"4">
$1 #=> "6"
$2 #=> "+"
$3 #=> "4"
```

#### Performing calculations with dynamic operands and operator

Note that these are still strings. We have to convert them to integers via [`to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-to_i) in order to perform operations on them:

```
$1.to_i #=> 6
$3.to_i #=> 4

$1.to_i + $3.to_i #=> 10
```

But I've hard-coded the [`+`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Fixnum.html#method-i-2B). To make the method call dynamic, we have to use [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-send):

```
6.send("+", 4)             #=> 10
$1.to_i.send($2, $3.to_i)  #=> 10
```

#### Replacing a placeholder with a value

Finally, we have to replace `__` with our result. This can be done with [`sub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-sub):

```
"7. 6 + 4 = __".sub("__", "10")
#=> "7. 6 + 4 = 10"
```

That's it. Now you have to incorporate these steps into your loop.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, will try that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a simple solution

```rb
out = File.open("out.txt",'w+')
File.open("math1.txt", 'r+') do |file|
  file.each_line do |line|
    calc = eval(line.split(".")[1].split("=")[0])
    out.write(line.sub('__',calc.to_s))
  end
end
```

Comment: `eval` is very dangerous when parsing a file from an external source. What if the file contains a line like `".\`rm -rf /\`="`?

Comment: you could insert a filter for example to remove $ and `.
But I assume the file comes from a reliable source and I wanted to show a simpler example.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate it.

Comment: Implementing a filter that for example removes `"\`"` would not solve the problem at all. There are too many other ways to call system commands or to just use Ruby to do dangerous things. Using `eval` on files from a *reliable source*, is basically the same as allowing the author of that files to use your computer unobserved for a while. It allow him to do everything: read, copy or upload files (ssh keys anyone?), manipulate data or add backdoors to your system. And he could also clean the file to cover tracks after doing harm...

Comment: How would you execute system commands filtering out ` and $?
you cond use a reg exp to only allow 0-9,+ -

Comment: This is the original file, what can I do to have the words
Math Homework appear as well in the code?

Math Homework

1. 1 + 3 = __
2. 2 + 2 = __
3. 0 + 9 = __
4. 3 + 4 = __
5. 5 + 2 = __
6. 2 + 5 = __
7. 6 + 4 = __
8. 7 + 1 = __
9. 9 + 9 = __
10. 10 + -1 = __

Comment: out.write("Math Homework") whenever you want it written in file

Comment: Thanks, that worked but is there any other way to just keep the wording in the same file and the make the code run after the wording so that we don't have to add it manually?